# CGContextRef draws fuzzy or blurred images

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, cgcontextref

I created new CGContext using:

```
        NSUInteger width = newRect.size.width;
        NSUInteger height = newRect.size.height;

        NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
        NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
        NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;

        UInt32 * pixels;
        pixels = (UInt32 *) calloc(height * width, sizeof(UInt32));
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

        CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little);

        CGContextSetShouldAntialias(self.graphContext, false);
        CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(self.graphContext, kCGInterpolationHigh);
```

When I trying to draw circle or text using this context I get weird fuzzy objects like these:

[image]

[image]

When I set CGContextSetShouldAntialias to true images becomes too blured:

[image]

[image]

I want text and images becomes such as usual label or views (not blurred but not fuzzy). I can use only this approach to obtain CGContextRef.

My code for drawing text:

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, rect );

NSAttributedString* attString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                                  initWithString:text
                                  attributes:self.attributes];

CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)attString);

CTFrameRef frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter,
                         CFRangeMake(0, [attString length]), path, NULL);

CTFrameDraw(frame, self.graphContext);

CFRelease(frame);
CFRelease(path);
CFRelease(framesetter);
```

Code for drawing circles:

```
    CGRect minPath = CGRectMake(xPoint - extremaPointWidth / 2, minY - extremaPointWidth /2, extremaPointWidth, extremaPointWidth);

    CGContextAddPath(self.graphContext, createRoundedCornerPath(minPath, cornerRadius));
    CGContextFillPath(self.graphContext);
```

Creating rounding path

```
// create a mutable path
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

// get the 4 corners of the rect
CGPoint topLeft = CGPointMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y);
CGPoint topRight = CGPointMake(rect.origin.x + rect.size.width, rect.origin.y);
CGPoint bottomRight = CGPointMake(rect.origin.x + rect.size.width, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height);
CGPoint bottomLeft = CGPointMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height);

CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, topLeft.x + cornerRadius, topLeft.y);

CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, topRight.x - cornerRadius, topRight.y);

CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(path, NULL, topRight.x, topRight.y, topRight.x, topRight.y + cornerRadius);

CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, bottomRight.x, bottomRight.y - cornerRadius);

CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(path, NULL, bottomRight.x, bottomRight.y, bottomRight.x - cornerRadius, bottomRight.y);

CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, bottomLeft.x + cornerRadius, bottomLeft.y);

CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(path, NULL, bottomLeft.x, bottomLeft.y, bottomLeft.x, bottomLeft.y - cornerRadius);

CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, topLeft.x, topLeft.y + cornerRadius);

CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(path, NULL, topLeft.x, topLeft.y, topLeft.x + cornerRadius, topLeft.y);

return path;
```

Thanks.

UPDATE:
When I draw just straight line or rectangle it's fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get weird fuzzy objects like these

No, you don't. You get a bitmap. You have to do something *else* in order to get an object that you can *see* — and you have not shown what it is that you do. But isn't that the whole issue? You have to turn a bitmap into a UIImage, and that takes *code*. If you do it in a blocky, pixellated way, you will get a blocky, pixellated result.

I used your bitmap context code and drew a filled circle into it, and then turned the bitmap context into a UIImage and put that UIImage in a UIImageView, and it looks like this:

[image]

Well, *that* seems smooth enough. So surely it isn't your bitmap context that's the problem, but how you are getting from there to something *visible* that's the problem.

However, personally I don't understand why you're going to all this trouble. If your goal is to generate an image you are going to display in the interface, why don't you just use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` like everyone else?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So maybe, right question is, how to obtain image correct? I use these lines:            CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(self.graphContext);
            UIImage *point = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];

Comment: Right, so you're using a scale=1 graphics context in a scale=2 world. If, as I suggested in my answer, you use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` with scale 0, that whole issue would be taken care of for you.

Comment: But how I can fix this issue in my case? I really tried use your suggestion before I came across with bitmap and need only bitmap. In my case I need to draw thousands circles and UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions make me some troubles

Comment: "and UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions make me some troubles" Really? Well, maybe your question should have been about _that_.

Comment: I mean, that I discovered, that bitmap is working faster than UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions. I tried to create 50 images  (1200x250), each of them contains about circles. Since UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions retrieve last pushed context, after some time I get memory error (Unable to allocate .... bytes for bitmap data...).

Comment: "I tried to create 50 images (1200x250)" Then you use 50 calls to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` and `UIGraphicsEndImageContext`, thus releasing each context. You don't try to reuse a context for multiple images!

Comment: "Right, so you're using a scale=1 graphics context in a scale=2 world." Can you help me to change scale of my context or it is impossible?

Comment: One possibility: don't call `imageWithCGImage:`. Call `imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:` and supply a better scale, like 2. But of course if you _just_ do that, you will have to double all your numbers.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to use another initializer. And about  UIGraphicsEndImageContext: I double checked that I've closed all opened contexts. I think UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions is calling last context on stack and maybe this context is using by system in another place, so it cannot be popped.

Comment: OK. I still think that the problems you were having with UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions would have been a much more interesting question! :)

Comment: So at the and I returned back to UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions, scaling bitmap context was a bit problematic. I even used it in background and it works fine, but at end of all I changes all logic about drawing. Thanks.